# update an Access table using an email?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have several databases that all produce reports. I need to automate the sending of these reports to a frequently changing list of people. We have a distribution list that is constantly out of date. I have built a central planner to run the reports and am now working on sending the reports out properly. I figured I would just add a custom distro list to my central planner and get people to send an email containing which reports they need to it. come to find out we can't use outlook on the server.

So what I want to do is

1. make a form containing check boxes for which reports a person needs
2. email that form using CDOsys because we can't have outlook on the servers
3. have persons email me back that form completed. Which I feed to access manually
4. use the table to send the correct reports to the correct peoples. also CDOsys

I wanted to make this as simple as possible for people. So they can literally just check off which reports they need, click a button to send the database an update. and boom they are done. If anyone has a simpler or better way to accomplish this feel free to recommend it.

I saw that older versions of access had a data collection tool that used to be able to update tables from emails is that no longer possible?

Comment: Does your organization use Sharepoint? If so, you could create an Access Web app. The Collect Data via Email functionality isn't supported in Access versions after 2010. Other than a web app, it would probably be easiest to send your contacts an Excel spreadsheet with report options and then import the returned spreadsheets into a table in Access.

Comment: It's my understand that Access 2013 will run CollectData but db must be built with Access 2007/2010. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Access-2013-bc006fc3-5b48-499e-8c7d-9a2dfef68e2f. Don't know if that carried over to 2016.

Comment: We do have a Sharepoint actually. Currentlywe're using an excel sheet via email  and because no one claims ownership of it there are a few different versions floating around here and there. Hense why im trying to change it. Im not supper familiar with sharepoint features but I think I can just post the form on the sharepoint and link it to the database somehow?